# Rails jquery how to get the dynamic add content id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I used Rails5.2.

In my `html.erb`, I had to dynamic add the `_form.html.erb`.

**The link is:**

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-pencil mr2 fa-fw'></i>Edit".html_safe, edit_question_answer_path(@question,@answer),remote: true %>
```

**The `edit.js.erb` is like:**

```
$("#answer_<%= @answer.id %> #answerEdit").removeClass("hide").html("<%= j render 'answers/form' %>");
```

**A part of the `_form.html.erb` just like :**

```
<%= form_for [@question,@answer] do |f| %>
  <div class="markdown">
    <div class="markdown-toolbar pb5">
      <%= render "layouts/markdown_toolbar" %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.text_area :content,class: "markdown-content border1",rows: 10 %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions pull-right">
      <%= link_to "Cancel", "javascript:void(0)",class: "btn btn-default",id: :formCancel %>
      <%= f.submit "Submmit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

A part of the **`markdown.js`** just like :

```
let txtBox = $("div.markdown .markdown-content");
console.log(txtBox.attr("id"))
```

When I click the `link`, I get the `_form.html.erb` to edit the answer,

But I just get the `console.log` undefined, What show I do can get the right id.

Anyone help? ,thanks so much!

Comment: The `markdown.js` is an asset? If it is, then I'm assuming it is executed on page load, and not when the `_form.html..erb` is rendered back after clicking the link. So in `markdown.js` the HTML element cannot be found because it doesn't exists in the DOM yet.

Comment: More information about when the code in `markdown.js` is called would be nice.